# Are brief blasphemous deliberate thoughts a mortal sin according to Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, sin, blasphemy

Are brief blasphemous deliberate thoughts a mortal sin according to Catholicism?

Answer (score 2):

[Mortal sin](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34987) (from *mors* = death) forfeits sanctifying grace and is the supernatural death of the soul. [St. Augustine defines it](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14004b.htm#III) as "something said, done or desired contrary to the eternal law."

To be a mortal sin, these conditions must be satisfied:

1. Knowledge (either natural or supernatural) of the act's sinfulness (offense to God).
2. Freely performing the sin.
3. Grave matter

In your scenario, #2 is satisfied because you say "deliberate". #3 is satisfied because blasphemy is a grave offense against God.

It's unclear if #1 is satisfied, you should confess it to a priest, who can help judge if such a sin is mortal.

Comment: The fact that the question was asked here suggests that condition #1 was not satisfied yesterday (but maybe it is satisfied now).